# Schengen in Dublin on ED Visa but wants to visit other Schengen cities for vacation

Tags: schengen, paris, amsterdam, rome, dublin

I am an English teacher with a student from Vietnam. Can she, with a Schengen visa and studying English in Dublin, travel on holiday to Amsterdam, Paris and Rome and then return to Dublin to continue her studies?
She already has an Italian Visa to visit for ONLY 4 days but on this first journey, she is also visiting Paris and 4 days is completely inadequate. Does she ALSO have to do the same at the French Embassy, et al?
She is so worried because she has already bought the tickets without being aware of the possible visa difficulties.
Thank you so much for your kind response.

Comment: What itinerary did she submit to the Italian authorities - did it include France and the Netherlands? How many days stay are planned in each destination? Is her Italian Schengen visa single or multiple entry and what are the visa validity dates? Ireland is not part of the Schengen zone, she cannot enter the Schengen zone solely on the basis of her Irish visa.

Comment: This https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

She has a Schengen visa, right? This visa has a **duration** of stay, a **validity period**, and a number of **entries**.

- Duration means how many days she can stay in Schengen (partial days count full).
- Validity means when those days can be taken (even if there are days left, they can't be used if the validity is over).
- Entries is the number of times she can enter through an **external** Schengen border. There is no limit on the number of internal Schengen border crossings.

When any of these are used up, she cannot visit the Schengen area any longer. So she will probably have to apply for a fresh visa to get more days, but that needs some care because visas cannot overlap.

Comment: Visas cannot overlap, but one can apply for a fresh visa to cover an extended trip.  So if she has a 4-day visa for a trip to Rome, and wants to tack on a trip to France and the Netherlands, she can apply to France or the Netherlands for a visa whose validity starts on the day after the Italian visa's validity expires.  There's nothing that explicitly requires a single visa to cover any given trip.